# Apply bundle adjustment to rectify images globally in the context of image stitching in python/openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

I am trying to perform image registration on potentially hundreds of aerial images taken from a camera mounted on a UAV. I think it is safe to assume that I know the ordering of the images, and hopefully, sequential images will overlap.

I have read some papers that suggest using a CNN to find the homography matrix can vastly outperform the old school feature descriptor matching with RANSAC song and dance. My issue is that I don't quite understand how to stitch more than 2 images together. It seems to me that to register image 100 in the same coordinate frame as image 1 using the cv2.warpPerspective function, I would do I100*H1*H2*H3...H99. Even if the error in each transform is small after 100 applications it seems like it would be huge. My understanding is that the solution to this problem is bundle adjustment.

I have looked into bundle adjustment a little bit but Im struggling to see how exactly I can use it. I have read the paper that many related stack overflow posts suggest "Automatic Panoramic Image Stitching using Invariant Features". In the section on bundle adjustment IF I understand the authors suggest that after building the initial panorama it is likely that image A will eventually overlap with multiple other images. Using the matched feature points in any images that overlap with A they basically calculate some adjustment...? I think to image A?

My question is using openCV how do I apply this adjustment? Let's say I have 3 images I1, I2, I3 all overlapping for a minimal example.

```
#assuimg CNN model predicts transform 
#I think the first step is find the homography between all images
H12 = cnnMod.predict(I1,I2)
H13 = cnnMod.predict(I1,I3)
H23 = cnnMod.predict(I2,I3)

outI2 = cv2.warpPerspective(I2,H12,(maxWidth, maxHeight),flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
outI3 = cv2.warpPerspective(I2,H23,(maxWidth, maxHeight),flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

#now would I do some bundle voodoo?
#what would it look like?
#which of the bundler classes should I use?

#would it look like this?

#or maybe the input is features?
voodoo = cv2.bundleVoodoo([H12,H13,H23])

golaballyRectifiedI2 = cv2.warpPerspective(outI2,voodoo[2],(maxWidth, maxHeight),flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

The code is my best guess at what a solution might look like but clearly I have no idea what I am doing. I've not been able to find anything that actually shows how the bundle adjustment is done.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea underlying image alignment through bundle adjustment is that, rather than matching pairs of 2D points (x, x') across pairs of images, you posit the existence of 3d points X that, ideally, project onto matched tuples of 2D points (x, x', x'', ...) matched among corresponding tuples of images. You then solve for the location of the X's and the camera parameters (extrinsics, and intrinsics if the camera is uncalibrated) that minimize the (robustified, usually) RMS reprojection error over all 2d points and images.

Depending on your particular setup and scene, you may make some simplifying assumptions, e.g.:

- That the X's all belong to the same plane (which you can arbitrarily choose as the world's Z=0 plane). This is useful, for example, when stitching images of a painting, or aerial images on relatively flat ground with relatively small extent so one can ignore the earth's curvature.
- Or that the X's are all on the WGS84 ellipsoid.
  Both the above assumptions remove one free coordinate from X, effectively reducing the problem's dimensionality.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. It does help with some of the concepts. Im still not clear on how to use bundle adjustment tho... Say I have 4 pictures, and 200 3d points, I solve for the 4x camera parameters and minimize the projection error. Then what? I have intrinsic and extrinsic parms and 3d points but how does that get me to homographies? Do I project all 3d points into the image space with camera 1 and solve a transform for image 1? like ```finalH = initialH@adjustH```?

Comment: "Then what" depends on what you know about the scene and/or on your goal. If you just want to stitch a panorama, and the scene is so far away from the camera that you can ignore the camera translations, then you can compute the homography induced by just the rotation part of the motion (```K * R * inv(K)```), and use that to warp.
On the other hand, if this is a mapmaking application, you may use the solved locations/poses to project the images onto an ellipsoid, or geoid, or DSM. It depends... [also, pls remember to upvote or accept the answer, if you find it useful]